# I would like to know about the meaningful usage of Optional orElseGet

Tags: java, option-type

First, let me clarify that this is not a question asking "how to use" or "differences" of this method.

I have a query to lookup one object by ID in DB.

If this ID is invalid, no object will be returned, which will result in an error.

To prevent this from happening, I wrapped the return object in Optional, and the problem was solved.

At that moment, a new problem arose.

In the context of retrieving this object, I found that I had only two options.

1. Since there is an object returned, the object is used normally.
2. There is no object returned, so there is nothing we can do other than null or Throw.

My return object is UserEntity.

i.e. when i use the value

```
UserEntity user = getUser().orElstGet(null);
```

or

```
UserEntity user = getUser().orElstThrow(...);
```

I don't think there is anything else that can be done.

If the object I wanted didn't come in the response, UserEntity user; There is no object other than null that can be contained in .

Obviously something is wrong, or I think there is a more correct usage.

can you give me some advice?

Comment: I'd say `orElseThrow` is the correct behavior if a null result is something that shouldn't happen.

Comment: I use `Optional#ifPresent` to go the next step in my code only if I got a value

Comment: `.orElstGet(null)` is almost always wrong. `null` tells optional to get the alternative value from null, which will cause a nullpointerexception from your own code. Perhaps you mean `.orElse(null)`, which will set `user` to null if there is no value found.

Comment: `there is nothing we can do other than null or Throw.` well, no you can still return a default value that is not null. Easiest example would be an empty String.

Comment: It sounds like you think that `orElseGet` is *always* applicable, for every situation. No it is not, just like every other method. It looks like `orElseThrow` is more suitable here, as you said.

Comment: The meaningful usage of `Optional.orElseGet(Suppler<T> s)` is that `orElseGet()` calls `get()` on the `Supplier` you specify if the `Optional` contains `null`. It therefore makes no sense whatsoever to specify `null` for the `Supplier`. What you want here is either `orElse()` or `orElseThrow()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't exactly give enough context to give a meaningful specific answer.

For users, a sensible usage could be

```
UserEntity user = userRepo.getUser(userId).orElseGet(() -> userRepo.getGuestUser());
```

It really depends on the use case.

Answer (score 2):

Optional is a type-level solution for representing optional values instead of null references. So ideally, when you working with Optional, you can have multiple options to avoid null checking. Example, for your use case:

```
getUser().isPresent()
```

is equivalent to (Let pretend your getUser() now return User instead of Optional)

```
getUser() != null
```

Also, Optional provides a lot of methods ([which is clearly stated in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)), especially functional style, which is convenient to deal with when it contains an actual value or not.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to do this the following way:

Whenever I expect the query to always return exactly one record, and if that record isn't found it means that there is an unexpected problem, I name the method `getSomething(...)` and I make it return the entity itself.

Whenever I expect the query to return one record or nothing, I name the method `findSomething(...)` and I make it return `Optional<...>`.

The `getSomething(...)` method can be implemented in terms of the `findSomething(...)` method. Like this:

```
// Returns an empty Optional if there is no user with the given id
Optional<UserEntity> findUserById(long id) {
    return ...;
}

// Throws an EntityNotFoundException if there is no user with the given id
UserEntity getUserById(long id) {
    return findUserById(id).orElseThrow(
        () -> new EntityNotFoundException("No UserEntity found with id " + id));
}
```

Comment: Does the Optional type return null if not found like `{user: null}`. From the docs, empty(): Returns an empty Optional instance. I'm not sure what to make of it.

Comment: No. `Optional` is really a more safe replacement for `null`. Instead of `null`, you would return an empty `Optional`, and use the methods of class `Optional` to check if it's empty or contains a value and work with it. The main advantage is that it's more explicit than `null`, so you don't get unexpected problems like `NullPointerException` as easily.

Comment: Another way to think about `Optional` is that it is a collection that can contain at most one element. So it's like a `List`, for example, that can be empty or contain a single element. An empty `Optional` (just like an empty `List`) is not the same thing as `null`.